# Saving a multidimensional array into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, multidimensional-array

This is my codes for my form,

```html
    <table id="dataTable" class="form-control">
      <label for="Monday">Monday</label>
      <input type="button" value="Add Schedule" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <p>
            <td>
              <label>Start Time</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[1][]">
            </td>
            <td>
              <label>End Time</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[1][]">
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <table id="dataTable1" class="form-control">
          <label for="Monday">Tuesday</label>
          <input type="button" value="Add Schedule" onClick="addRow('dataTable1')" />
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <p>
                <td>
                  <label>Start Time</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[2][]">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <label>End Time</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[2][]">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <table id="dataTable2" class="form-control">
          <label for="Monday">Wednesday</label>
          <input type="button" value="Add Schedule" onClick="addRow('dataTable2')" />
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <p>
                <td>
                  <label>Start Time</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[3][]">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <label>End Time</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[3][]">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <table id="dataTable3" class="form-control">
          <label for="Monday">Thursday</label>
          <input type="button" value="Add Schedule" onClick="addRow('dataTable3')" />
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <p>
                <td>
                  <label>Start Time</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[4][]">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <label>End Time</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[4][]">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <table id="dataTable4" class="form-control">
          <label for="Monday">Friday</label>
          <input type="button" value="Add Schedule" onClick="addRow('dataTable4')" />
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <p>
                <td>
                  <label>Start Time</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[5][]">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <label>End Time</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[5][]">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

The "**add schedule**" button allows user to add another row of "start time and end time for the specific day.

This is my code to get the values from the form into the database,

```html
<?php 

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) { 
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
} 

 else { 
  foreach($_POST[ "startTime"] as $day=>$startTimes){ 

    foreach($startTimes as $timeIndex=>$startTime){ 

      $endTime = $_POST["endTime"][$day][$timeIndex]; 

        $sql = "INSERT INTO timetableschedule (name, day, startTime, endTime) VALUES ('$name', '$day', '$startTime', '$endTime')"; 

    } 

  } 

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { 
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); 
} 

echo "Records added"; 
mysqli_close($con); 

} 

?>
```

**$day** refers to the day of the week. So Monday will be represented using "1" and so on.

**$timeIndex** refers to the number of the row it is representing. for example "Monday 1200h 1300h" is entered, this is row 1, but in array the value will be "0". If another set of values is entered to Monday, "Monday 1500h 2100h" this will be row 2 and in array it will be "1".

**Problem faced**
When echo out the information entered to the form,

echo  $timeIndex .$startTime . $day . $endTime;

I will get,

0 1200 1 1300 //First row of time entered into Monday

1 1400 1 1500

2 1700 1 1900

0 1300 2 1500 //Tuesday

1 1600 2 1700

0 1400 5 1700 //Friday

But when i execute the php code to enter the values into the database, only the last row of data was entered into the database. Meaning only "0 1400 5 1700" is entered only.

I want the data from Monday to be entered into the database as well, but i do not know what code should i put in in order for this to work.

Comment: You are executing `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))`  ouside the loops so only the last values will be inserted

Comment: May I know how should I code it to insert all values? :) @Mihai

Comment: Put this code `mysqli_query($con,$sql);` immediately after `$sql=...` and remove `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { 
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));  `